# Attach source to endeca_assembler-3.1.2.jar

Tags: endeca

Do anyone know where i can find source zip file. I want to attach source to endeca_assembler-3.1.2.jar.

Thanks in advance

Comment: ok i got your point.. but i want to debug ResultsListHandler and i set BP in it but not working. Any advice on how to do it?

Comment: Is there a particular problem you are trying to solve that we can try and help with?

Comment: actually there is no such problem, I am getting desired output but just wanted to debug various handlers and understand them how they work. I decompiled them using jadclipse but on debugging them BP is never reached. Again thank you for your response :)